# Finding words that start with character will fail with new line

Tags: python, string, hashtag

I am trying to write a program that highlights hashtags in tweets. but the program will fail if the tweet contains a new line, the program will work if it is just one line. Why is it failing when there is a new line in the data? I get the error `index out of range`.

```
def highlight(data):
    for word in data.split(" "):
        if word[0] == "#":
            print "<FONT COLOR=\"brown\">" + word + "</FONT>",
        else:
            print word,

highlight("""hello world this
    is a #test that i am #writing.""")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work:

```
def highlight(data):
    for word in data.split():
        if word[0] == "#":
            print "<FONT COLOR=\"brown\">" + word + "</FONT>",
        else:
            print word,

highlight("""hello world this
    is a #test that i am #writing.""")
```

This will split the text up by newlines and by whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Because a newline will make `data.split(" ")` contain `''`s. You're trying to get the first element of that, and, well:

```
In [4]: ''[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6f70a0cbdc74> in <module>()
----> 1 [][0]

IndexError: list index out of range

In [6]: a = """
   ...: hello world this
   ...:     is a #test that i am #writing."""

In [7]: a.split(' ')
Out[7]:
['\nhello',
 'world',
 'this\n',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'is',
 'a',
 '#test',
 'that',
 'i',
 'am',
 '#writing.']
```

Just change it to `data.split()` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the second line of the tweet, there are four whitespaces.

```
"""test
    other_test""" == "test\n    other_test"
```

So if you split that string by a whitespace, you will get three empty strings.

```
>>> "test\n    other_test".split(" ")
['test\n', '', '', '', 'other_test']
```

Now if you try to access the first character of the string `''`, the character index is out of range.

To prevent this error, either use `data.split()` or check if the current string is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have a "word" first:

```
def highlight(data):
    for word in data.split(" "):
        if word and word[0] == "#":
            print "<FONT COLOR=\"brown\">" + word + "</FONT>",
        else:
            print word,
```

*In the future when asking, it helps to include the full text of your error message.*